# AWS - nodejs SDK - CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.initiateAuth - CredentialsError: Missing credentials in config

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to get authentication working through my API using AWS Cognito with a user pool. I have a user created through an AWS Cognito User Pool and I'm trying to log in with the user.

The error I'm getting is `CredentialsError: Missing credentials in config`. Specifically it was telling me that I needed an `IdentityPoolId`. But I can't seem to find this `IdentityPoolId` in my AWS console. Where the heck do I get this from for my user pool? All I see is a Pool id and a Pool ARN.

[image]

Relevant source code:

```
var aws = require('aws-sdk');
aws.config.update({
    region: 'us-east-1',
    credentials: new aws.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
        IdentityPoolId: '???'
    })
});


var authUser = function(params, callback)
{
    if (!params || !params.Email || !params._password)
    {
        callback(new Error('Invalid parameters.'));
        return false;
    }

    var cognito = new aws.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider();

    var authParams = {
        AuthFlow: 'USER_SRP_AUTH', // not sure what this means...
        ClientId: conf.AWSConfig.ClientId,
        AuthParameters: {
            Username: params.Email,
            Password: params._password
        }
    };

    cognito.initiateAuth(authParams, function(err, data)
    {
        if (err)
        {
            console.log('Error details: ' + util.inspect(err));
            callback(err);
            return false;
        }
        callback(null, {success: true, data: data});
    });
}
```

For the `authParams` object, I'm not sure what the `AuthFlow` should be. Looking at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html#initiateAuth-property it seemed like `USER_SRP_AUTH` was what I should likely be using.

**Edit:**

I believe I may have found where to get my `IdentityPoolId`. I viewed my `Federated Identities` section and added in the appropriate `User Pool` under the `Authentication Providers` section while editing the identity pool.

[image]

I associated the `Authentication Provider` for `Cognito` to my User Pool that I created by entering the `User Pool ID` and `App Client ID` for that user pool. Now with the same code using that `Identity pool ID` I'm getting the error `CredentialsError: Missing credentials in config`. It says `Unauthorized access is not supported for this identity pool`. OK... I'm trying to authorize the user... Do I need to create an Unauthenticated role so that users can authenticate when they're not authenticated? That seems silly if that's what I need to do.

**Edit 2:**

I should also note that I was able to log in and get an `AccessToken` as well as an `IdToken` and `RefreshToken` using the Javascript SDK (not nodejs). I did this without the need of an `IdentityPoolId`. The only things I needed were a `UserPoolId` and a `ClientId`.

```
var authenticateUser = function(onSuccessCallback)
{
    var authData = {
        Username: getUserName(), // gets username from an html text field
        Password: getPassword()  // gets password from an html password field
    };

    var authDetails = new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.AuthenticationDetails(authData);

    var cognitoUser = getCognitoUser();

    cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authDetails,
    {
        onSuccess: function(result)
        {
            console.log('access token: ' + result.getAccessToken().getJwtToken());
            console.log('idToken: ' + result.idToken.jwtToken);
            console.log(result);

            if (onSuccessCallback && typeof(onSuccessCallback) == 'function')
            {
                onSuccessCallback(cognitoUser);
            }
        },
        onFailure: function(err)
        {
            // UserNotConfirmedException: User is not confirmed.
            console.log('authError');
            alert(err);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Turns out that `initiateAuth` was not at all what I wanted to be doing. I was also missing an npm package called `amazon-cognito-identity-js`. After installing that I updated my code as follows:

```
var authUser = function(params, callback)
{
    if (!params || !params.Email || !params._password)
    {
        callback(new Error('Invalid parameters.'));
        return false;
    }

    var poolData = {
        UserPoolId: conf.AWSConfig.UserPoolId,
        ClientId: conf.AWSConfig.ClientId
    };

    var userPool = new aws.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUserPool(poolData);
    var authData = {
        Username: params.Email,
        Password: params._password
    };

    var authDetails = new aws.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.AuthenticationDetails(authData);
    var userData = {
        Username: params.Email,
        Pool: userPool
    };

    var cognitoUser = new aws.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUser(userData);

    cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authDetails, {
        onSuccess: function(result)
        {
            callback(null, {success: true, data: result});
        },
        onFailure: function(err)
        {
            console.log('authUser error: ' + util.inspect(err));
            callback(err);
        }
    });
}
```

I am now successfully getting a response with tokens! Hooray!

Comment: Hi @Jared Price Can I get the complete source code on git, because it's not working for me.

Comment: The new way to do this is to use aws-amplify

Comment: @astroanu aws-amplify has goals to be a library for the browser. So, this answer is still correct for backend Node programs.

Comment: @BrandonBradley the old repo is now *moved* future implementations would be done on the amplify repo.

Comment: @BrandonBradley amplify is just for front end right? Also as per the answer, if you have MFA enabled, how would you actually send the request back to the front end then the code back to node without getting two MFA codes? I ran into this issue implementing my authentication flow similar to the answer

Answer (score 2):

Just set up the Authentication credentials with AWS and use the config options.

```
const settings = Settings.GetSettings('Cognito');
const auth = {
  region: settings['region'],
  apiVersion: settings['api-version'],
  accessKeyId: settings['access-key-id'],
  secretAccessKey: settings['secret-access-key']
};
const CognitoIdentityServiceProvider = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider(auth);
var config = {
  UserPoolId: settings['user-pool-id'],
  Username: guid
};
CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.adminDeleteUser(config, function (err, data) {
  if (err) {
    reject(err);
  } else {
    resolve(data);
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi @Rick, How do we get the accessKeyId and secretAccessKey ?

I have created this under one of my IAM users under the security credentials in aws console. But still I am getting the following exception,

UnrecognizedClientException: The security token included in the request is invalid. 

This exception is from the aws sdk nodejs.

Comment: @Karthikeyan the following link covers setting up credentials - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/loading-node-credentials-shared.html