# Specifying username/password for CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider

Tags: android, amazon-cognito, aws-userpools

I am trying to use `CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider` with a User Pool requiring login through the User Pool with a username and password. I have finally got to the point where I am getting the error `Unauthorized access is not supported for this identity pool` (and yay! for finally getting that far!), which is kind of what I was expecting to see, seeing as I can't for the life of me figure out how I'm supposed to tell the Provider what the username and password are.

How am I supposed to use this to log in my users? I have been [told](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48101827/aws-cognito-sign-in-android/49796952#49796952) that I don't need to use Federated Identities or any other authentication provider other than User Pools to be able to log in, but can this be done with the `CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider`?

Comment: Can you provide code? Since I can't find any info related with `Unauthorized access is not supported for this identity pool` error except [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43235877/aws-nodejs-sdk-cognitoidentityserviceprovider-initiateauth-credentialserro) (But it using Node.js). Most of the post are related with `Unauthenticated access is not supported for this identity pool`

Comment: It's possible I might have mistyped the one word there, I'll have to check tomorrow. Meanwhile, I'm hoping that authenticating through the normal route for the User Pool, then passing the resultant token to the `.logins` member of the `CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider` will be what I need (and I hope I'm giving that what it needs for the provider, since I haven't found much in the way of documentation for that).

Comment: It's also possible the code I had when I posted this doesn't exist anymore, as it's gone through about foxy

Comment: About fifty million iterations since then (my backspace on my phone is too close to my enter key).